# Google colab issue

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, spacy

I tried to do this:

```
!python -m spacy download en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg
```

Got this message:

> 2021-06-29 22:50:24.331283: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53]
> Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
>
> ✘ No compatible package found for 'en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg' (spaCy
> v3.0.6)

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using the wrong name. A v2 version while having SpaCy v3 installed. Try this:

```
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
```

Source: 
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8243

Comment: Did as suggested. The problem remains the same. The whole command sequence is below:
! pip install -U spacy
! pip install spacy-transformers
! python -m spacy download en_core_web_trf
! python -m spacy download en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg

The first 3 statements executed successfully. The last one gave the following error.

2021-07-02 21:38:30.700280: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0

✘ No compatible package found for 'en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg' (spaCy
v3.0.6)
Please help. Thanks

Comment: The problem is that you cant use `en_trf_bertbaseuncased_lg` with SpaCy v3, since it belongs to the v2 version. The equivalent for v3 is the command I suggested. (also, see the githup post).